# Running Phonegap Android app on OSX

Tags: android, ios, macos, cordova

I am trying, to no avail, to run an Android version of a Phonegap app I have made.

The app works fine on iOS when running:

```
phonegap run ios
```

However, when I run:

```
phonegap run android
```

I get

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android'`
```

But nothing happens. When I run:

```
phonegap run android --verbose
```

I get the error(s):

```
BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1
```

and

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/*/Google Drive/Websites/angular-phonegap/*/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I faced a similar problem in the past that involved editing my PATH variable, not sure if this is the same issue or what. In any case, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hope you are building the app on mac machine?? just check you have all the requirement for android (adk bundle)[http://www.panopticdev.com/blog2014/phonegap-mac-osx-setup-configuration-android-ios/]

Comment: @Iftikhar Yes I am doing it on a mac and have all requirements etc...

Comment: ??? Any ideas? The link you left is dead.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you not have all requirements, please check another time, as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/8de97feba2fa883298eb9c99be0c425c73960f1a/cordova-lib/src/cordova/run.js), cordova fail with this error where not find a specific platform command to run.
Follow these instruction:

1. Check that the java sdk is already installed and already in your Path.
2. Check to have already installed android studio or sdk standalone and the bin folder of the sdk is in Path.
3. Check to have installed ant ( on Mac install it with brew, this is the best option ) and to have it in path.

For a complete list to check refer to this [cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide).

Be patient and follow the step one by one, your problem must be in one of these steps.

Comment: I think i have all of the steps you listed installed. When I run echo $PATH I get /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/platform-tools

Comment: try to check manually if the path is really correct, run `java -version` and then `ant -version`
If they are correctly settted, try to run the ant build.xml file manually from the android project root, this will out the command that you miss to complete the build.

Comment: `java -version = java version "1.7.0_79"`. `ant -version = Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014`

Comment: Ok, now go under platforms/android ( relative to your cordova project ) and run `ant clean debug` the build fail? if fail, the error is the same of `cordova build android` command?

Comment: Ran: `ant clean debug` produced alot of code in terminal. Main part being: 
     `[aapt] invalid resource directory name: /Users/alan/Google Drive/Websites/angular-phonegap/merseycare-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res Icon

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1`

Comment: Check the build.xml at the specific row, probably it fail to find some file, proguard or another, when you find in your buil.xml file version the command that fail.
Another solution is to try the complete clean of your project ( cordova clean, ant clean and finally remove/add platforms and plugin ( in this case probably everything working fine in the end but you don't find why )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76999/discussion-between-alan-and-phemt-latd).